# DRF regex search

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to search and return my products in a certain order and have a regex that handles the search, the problem is, I'm not sure how to apply it to the search field in DRF search_filters.

Here's the regex that I would like to use `"^(?P<name>\w+ ?,?)"` - any name that starts with the entered text and possibly ends with a space or a comma. If possible I would also like to apply a tokenized ordering, so "rice", "rice " and "rice," are returned before "ricenoodle".

I'm trying to use the regex like that `search_fields = ['^(?P<name>\w+ ?,?)']` but all I get back is an error like that `Cannot resolve keyword '(?P<name>\w+ ?,?)$' into field`.

DRF states that to use regex I need to use "$name", and has a link to django docs that have 0 info on how to construct search fields with a regex (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields).

How should I construct `search_fields`?

Comment: You cannot assign a regular expression as a search field. If you want to be able to search a field named 'name' with regex, you should do `search_fields = ['$name',]`. This will allow you to search that field using any regular expression you want.

Comment: @BjörnKristinsson ah I see, so I would need to actually pass a regex as a "search" parameter like so `?search=^stuff$`. That's quite weird, perhaps it would make more sense to write my own implementation using `get_queryset` method.

Answer (score 1):

By default DRF will return case-insensitive partial matches against your search field and search parameter may contain multiple search terms, which should be whitespace and/or comma separated. If multiple search terms are used then objects will be returned in the list only if all the provided terms are matched.

1. '^' Starts-with search.
2. '=' Exact matches.
3. '@' Full-text search. (Currently only supported Django's MySQL
   backend.)
4. '$' Regex search.

example:

```
search_fields = ('=username', '=email')
```

you can find more search pattern and how to use [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter)

Comment: This is pretty much outlined in the documentation. Is there a way to customize how a regex search is going to be performed or is using `"$name"` the only option?

Comment: sorry @Eugene i didn't get your point properly. Normally DRF search field itself do partial search , say string arrays like ['hello', 'hi', 'how' ] if you just type h it will return all ['hello', 'hi', 'how'] , if you type 'ho' then it will return [ 'hello' , 'how'] , so it just mentioning the search field should enough i understand. If you need any regex pattern you can add $(regex_pattern_of_yours_search), this should work fine.